# Как использовать переменную

Tags: c#

У меня в главном классе создан метод **virtual**, в классах наследниках, он переопределяется. Так вот, мне нужно из классов наследников взять значение переменных, которые находятся в методе **override**. Я создаю объекты классов наследников, но мне нужно ввести аргументы и тут я не знаю что делать.
Вот весь код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using help3;

namespace help3
{

    public class Katalog
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Firm { get; set; }
        public string Diagonal { get; set; }
        public int Tv_tuner { get; set; }
        public string Resolution { get; set; }
        public string Type_matrix { get; set; }
        public string Type_sensor { get; set; } //Sensor
        public string Amount_hdd { get; set; } //Sensor

        public virtual int Price()
        {
            int value = 0;
            return value;
        }
    }
        public class LCD : Katalog
        {
            public int value { get; set; }
            public LCD(string Type, string Model, string Firm, string Diagonal, int Tv_Tuner, string Resolution, string Type_matrix, int value)
            {
                this.Type = Type;
                this.Model = Model;
                this.Firm = Firm;
                this.Diagonal = Diagonal;
                this.Tv_tuner = Tv_tuner;
                this.Resolution = Resolution;
                this.Type_matrix = Type_matrix;
                this.value = value;
            }
            public LCD(string l)
            {
                string[] split = l.Split(new Char[] { '*' });
                Model = split[0].Trim();
                Firm = split[1].Trim();
                Diagonal = split[2].Trim();
                Tv_tuner = int.Parse(split[3].Trim());
                Resolution = split[4].Trim();
                Type_matrix = split[5].Trim();
                value = int.Parse(split[6].Trim());
            }

        public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format("Модель {0}\nФирма {1}\nДиагональ {2}\nРазрешение {3}\nТип матрицы {4}\nСтоимость {5} гривны\n", Model, Firm, Diagonal, Resolution, Type_matrix, value);
            }
            public override int Price()
            {
                    value = (value + Tv_tuner) - (value * 5 / 100);
                    return value;
            }
    }
        public class Sensor : Katalog
        {

        public Sensor(string Type, string Model, string Firm, string Diagonal, int Tv_Tuner, string Resolution, string Type_sensor, string Amount_hdd)
        {
            this.Type = Type;
            this.Model = Model;
            this.Firm = Firm;
            this.Diagonal = Diagonal;
            this.Resolution = Resolution;
            this.Type_sensor = Type_sensor;
            this.Amount_hdd = Amount_hdd;
        }

        public int value { get; set; }

        public Sensor(string l)
        {

            string[] split = l.Split(new Char[] { '*' });
            Model = split[0].Trim();
            Firm = split[1].Trim();
            Diagonal = split[2].Trim();
            Resolution = split[3].Trim();
            Type_sensor = split[4].Trim();
            Amount_hdd = split[5].Trim();
            value = int.Parse(split[6].Trim());
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {

            return String.Format("Модель {0}\nФирма {1}\nДиагональ {2}\nРазрешение {3}\nOбъем HDD {4}\nТип сенсора {5}\nСтоимость {6} гривны\n", Model, Firm, Diagonal, Resolution, Amount_hdd, Type_sensor, value);
        }
        public override int Price()
        {
                value = ((value * 3 / 100) * 12 + value) / 12;
                return value;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            void CreateList()
            {
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader("Katalog.txt");
                List<LCD> Katalog_LCD = new List<LCD>();
                List<Sensor> Katalog_Sensor = new List<Sensor>();

                string line;
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.EndsWith("*"))
                    { Katalog_LCD.Add(new LCD(line)); }
                    else
                    { Katalog_Sensor.Add(new Sensor(line)); }
                }

                foreach (LCD a in Katalog_LCD)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                }
                foreach (Sensor b in Katalog_Sensor)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(b);
                }
            }
            CreateList();



            //Программа
                LCD L = new LCD();
                Sensor S = new Sensor();
                Console.WriteLine("Какой монитор вы желаете приобрести 1.LCD или 2.Сенсорный?");
                string buy;
                while (true)//Цикл для правильного ввода названия мониторов
                {
                    buy = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (buy == "1" || buy == "2") break;
                    else Console.WriteLine("Пожалуйста введите правильное название");
                }
                switch (buy)
                {
                    case "1":
                        Console.WriteLine("Желаете приопрести ТВ-тюнер всего за 299 гривен и получить скидку 5% на всю сумму покупки?");
                        string tv_tuner = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (tv_tuner == "+")
                        {
                            L.Price();
                            Console.WriteLine("Вы купили LCD монитор и ТВ-тюнер.\nСумма к оплате сo скидкой 5% {0} гривен.", L.value);

                        }
                        else if (tv_tuner == "-")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Вы купили LCD монитор.\nСумма к оплате {0} гривен.", L.value);
                        }
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        Console.WriteLine("Желаете взять кредит на 12 месяцев?");
                        string kredit = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (kredit == "+")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Вы взяли кредит, суммой {0} гривен, на 12 месяцев, под 3%.", S.value);
                            S.Price();
                            Console.WriteLine("Ежемесячная сумма погашения кредита, составляет {0} гривен.", S.value);
                        }
                        else if (kredit == "-")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Вы купили сенсорный монитор. Сумма к оплате {0} гривен.", S.value);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Создание метода]

[image: Переопределение]

[image: Создание объектов классов]

Comment: убери весь код, который не влияет на проблему, чтобы пример стал минимальным. Попробуй точнее сформулировать, в чем именно проблема или что ты хочешь получить. Пока ясно лишь, что что-то не так с методом `Price`

Comment: Я же всё выделил на фотографиях. Мне нужно использовать с классов наследников, переменную value, в главном методе. Как это сделать? Если есть вопросы - пишите, я всё постараюсь ясно расписать.

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что у вас в классах наследниках есть 2 конструктора, которые принимают значения, но вы создаёте экземпляры классов, ссылаясь на пустые конструкторы, которых, собственно, и нет)

Comment: Хорошо, а как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Либо добавить конструктор, который не принимает значений и задавать переменные какими-нибудь стандартными значениями, либо передать нужные параметры в уже существующие конструкторы

Comment: **this.value = value;** - это разве не конструктор?.

Comment: Нет, этим вы задаёте значение свойства, сейчас оформлю ответ

Comment: @Nort, я вижу что на фотографиях выделено. но непонятно что это значит. Единственная проблема которую видит студия - это конструктор без параметров, например: `LCD L = new LCD();`, хотя в классе объявлены только `public LCD(string Type, string Model, string Firm, string Diagonal, int Tv_Tuner, string Resolution, string Type_matrix, int value)` и `public LCD(string l)`. Но это никак не связано с доступом к полю `value` - оно отлично работает

Comment: Я это понимаю, но не могу понять как мне использовать переменную `value` и её значение, присвоенное с файла в массив.

Comment: @Nort, ты ее уже используешь, у тебя просто даже до запуска дело не доходит. Исправишь проблему с конструктором - и все заработает

Comment: @Grundy , я вас понял, но не знаю как исправить проблему. Я думаю вы поняли суть вопроса, что мне нужно взять значение с переменной, а не отправить ей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, у вас есть класс родитель

```
public class Katalog
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Firm { get; set; }
    public string Diagonal { get; set; }
    public int Tv_tuner { get; set; }
    public string Resolution { get; set; }
    public string Type_matrix { get; set; }
    public string Type_sensor { get; set; } //Sensor
    public string Amount_hdd { get; set; } //Sensor

    public virtual int Price()
    {
        int value = 0;
        return value;
    }
}
```

И класс наследник(упростил, чтобы не загромождать)

```
public class LCD : Katalog
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public LCD()
    {
        Type = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
        Model = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
        Firm = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
        Diagonal = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
        Tv_tuner = 0;
        Resolution = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
        Type_matrix = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
        Value = 0;
    }

    public LCD(string Type, string Model, string Firm, string Diagonal, int Tv_Tuner, string Resolution, string Type_matrix, int value)
    {
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Model = Model;
        this.Firm = Firm;
        this.Diagonal = Diagonal;
        this.Tv_tuner = Tv_Tuner;
        this.Resolution = Resolution;
        this.Type_matrix = Type_matrix;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override int Price()
    {
        Value = (Value + Tv_tuner) - (Value * 5 / 100);
        return Value;
    }
 }
```

В классе наследнике есть конструктор, не принимающий значения:

```
public LCD()
{
    Type = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
    Model = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
    Firm = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
    Diagonal = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
    Tv_tuner = 0;
    Resolution = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
    Type_matrix = "*НЕ ЗАДАНО*";
    Value = 0;
}
```

И конструктор, принимающий значения(идёт следом). Далее, создаём экземпляры класса:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LCD lcd1 = new LCD();
    LCD lcd2 = new LCD("qwe","dwdwd","zxcc","dwdwdwdwddddd", 50,"ddgrgrh","dwdbkuk",300);

    Console.WriteLine(lcd1.Price());
    Console.WriteLine(lcd2.Price());

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Экземпляр `lcd1` использует конструктор без параметров, в то время как `lcd2` конструктор с параметрами.

Comment: Спасибо, вы довольно хорошо объяснили, очень приятно. Вы в создании объекта передаете аргументы для конструктора в классе, а как мне использовать переменную `value`, которой значение присваивается с файла и потом существует в классе. По идее мне передавать в класс ничего не нужно, метод `createList` уже всё передал, мне наоборот нужно взять с класса значение переменной

Comment: @Nort У вас в корне не правильное видение. В методе `createList` у вас есть такая строчка `List<LCD> Katalog_LCD = new List<LCD>();`. Этим вы создаёте список `Katalog_LCD` тип `LCD`. Так же эта переменная локальна, то есть, вы не сможете использовать её вне метода

Comment: @Nort Вам нужно объявить этот список как глобальный и уже проводить эти манипуляции с ним, а после, в `main` вызывать метод `price` именно этого глобального списка

Comment: @Nort Вы оперируете понятием класс, но это не верно, класс, это такой же тип, как, например, `int`, но созданный вами. Правильно будет оперировать понятиями "Экземпляр", "Переменная" и тогда всё встанет на свои места)

Comment: Я понимаю, что `List<LCD> Katalog_LCD = new List<LCD>();` локальный, но по идее он передает информацию из файла в наследуемый класс, в метод в этом классе, а в методе в массив, который уже присваивает значение переменной `value`.
Хорошо, в принципе я понимаю, что Вы пишите, но не знаю как это сделать.
На счет класса не знал, спасибо, а Экземпляр - это же тот же объект, переменная для меня это название созданного типа.

Comment: @Nort Хорошо, смотрите, сделайте список `Katalog_LCD` глобальным, затем, присваивайте ему значения в методе `createList`(по сути, менять там ничего не придётся, нужно просто вытащить список из метода). После, в методе `main`, вы циклом проходитесь по всем записям в списке и вызываете у каждой метод `price`(например `Katalog_LCD[i].price()`) и уже после, так же циклом, вы выводите параметр `value`

Comment: Я не знаю как делать список глобальным, для этого нужно метод отдельный делать? В принципе я сделал, но по другому. Я взял тело метода `createList` и вставил его в метод `Main`, а сам метод `createList` удалил. В методе `Main` я уже использовал сам лист по вашему примеру, только без цикла. Получается я могу только таким образом использовать переменную и никак иначе?

Comment: @Nort Нет, просто вы сделали список локальным для метода `main` и поэтому он его видит) В принципе, так даже лучше. А для того, чтобы переменная была доступная для всех методов класса, нужно просто объявить её вне метода (По аналогии с вашими классами, где вы объявляли свойства, они были глобальны для данного класса)

Comment: спасибо, вы помогли мне.

Answer (score 0):

Если отвечать в контексте вашего вопроса, то вам нужно создавать свои объекты:

```
LCD L = new LCD();
Sensor S = new Sensor();
```

В соответствии с их конструкторами. Либо создать для них конструктора без параметров. С установкой в конструкторах каких-то значений по умолчанию.

Мне так-же не понятен смысл функции `createList`. Вы получаете два списка устройств из файла, но нигде не используете его. Если вы хотите использовать эти списки ниже в коде, то надо организовывать цикл, а лучше итератор. И вообще, свести устройства в один список `List<Catalog> Katalog = new List<Catalog>();`, используя полиморфизм, а затем определяя тип устройства через `is`. 
К слову, если использовать один объект, а не два, у Вас получится уйти от `switch`, предварительно инкапсулируя сообщения на консоль в методы класса.

---

С другой стороны, ваша архитектура ужасна. Используемое вами наследование порочно в данном случае. Я бы использовал скорее паттерн фасад, если конечно мне удалось понять что вы хотели получить. Этот паттерн доступно описан в паттернах проектирования Эрика фримена.

Также можно попробовать вынести отличия двух классов в один общий и агрегировать абстракцию. Это тоже сможет очень помочь.

Comment: Это курсовая работа и мне нужно всё делать строго как я делаю, не как иначе. С помощью `createList` я передаю информацию с файла в массив и вывожу его через метод.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать переменную можно так:
Взять тело метода `createList` и вставил его в метод Main, а сам метод `createList` удалить. В методе Main уже использовать переменные и методы класса. `Katalog_LCD[индекс].Price()` - запуск метода.
`Katalog_LCD[индекс].value` - использование переменной.

**Но я сделал через LINQ, вот полностью код, может кому поможет:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using help3;

namespace help3
{

    public class Katalog
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Firm { get; set; }
        public string Diagonal { get; set; }
        public int Tv_tuner { get; set; }
        public string Resolution { get; set; }
        public string Type_matrix { get; set; }
        public string Type_sensor { get; set; } //Sensor
        public string Amount_hdd { get; set; } //Sensor

        public virtual int Price()
        {
            int value = 0;
            return value;
        }
    }
        public class LCD : Katalog
        {
            public int value { get; set; }
            public LCD(string Type, string Model, string Firm, string Diagonal, int Tv_Tuner, string Resolution, string Type_matrix, int value)
            {
                this.Type = Type;
                this.Model = Model;
                this.Firm = Firm;
                this.Diagonal = Diagonal;
                this.Tv_tuner = Tv_tuner;
                this.Resolution = Resolution;
                this.Type_matrix = Type_matrix;
                this.value = value;
            }
            public LCD(string l)
            {
                string[] split = l.Split(new Char[] { '*' });
                Model = split[0].Trim();
                Firm = split[1].Trim();
                Diagonal = split[2].Trim();
                Tv_tuner = int.Parse(split[3].Trim());
                Resolution = split[4].Trim();
                Type_matrix = split[5].Trim();
                value = int.Parse(split[6].Trim());
            }

        public LCD()
        {

        }

        public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format("Модель {0}\nФирма {1}\nДиагональ {2}\nРазрешение {3}\nТип матрицы {4}\nСтоимость {5} гривны\n", Model, Firm, Diagonal, Resolution, Type_matrix, value);
            }
            public override int Price()
            {
                    value = (value + Tv_tuner) - (value * 5 / 100);
                    return value;
            }
    }
        public class Sensor : Katalog
        {
        public int value { get; set; }



        public Sensor(string l)
        {

            string[] split = l.Split(new Char[] { '*' });
            Model = split[0].Trim();
            Firm = split[1].Trim();
            Diagonal = split[2].Trim();
            Resolution = split[3].Trim();
            Type_sensor = split[4].Trim();
            Amount_hdd = split[5].Trim();
            value = int.Parse(split[6].Trim());
        }


        public Sensor()
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {

            return String.Format("Модель {0}\nФирма {1}\nДиагональ {2}\nРазрешение {3}\nOбъем HDD {4}\nТип сенсора {5}\nСтоимость {6} гривны\n", Model, Firm, Diagonal, Resolution, Amount_hdd, Type_sensor, value);
        }
        public override int Price()
        {
                value = ((value * 3 / 100) * 12 + value) / 12;
                return value;
        }
        public Sensor(string Type, string Model, string Firm, string Diagonal, int Tv_Tuner, string Resolution, string Type_sensor, string Amount_hdd, int value)
        {
            this.Type = Type;
            this.Model = Model;
            this.Firm = Firm;
            this.Diagonal = Diagonal;
            this.Resolution = Resolution;
            this.Type_sensor = Type_sensor;
            this.Amount_hdd = Amount_hdd;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader("Katalog.txt");
            List<LCD> Katalog_LCD = new List<LCD>();
            List<Sensor> Katalog_Sensor = new List<Sensor>();

            string line;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.EndsWith("*"))
                { Katalog_LCD.Add(new LCD(line)); }
                else
                { Katalog_Sensor.Add(new Sensor(line)); }
            }

            foreach (LCD a in Katalog_LCD)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("---LCD монитор---\n{0}", a);//Вывод ЛСД
            }
            foreach (Sensor b in Katalog_Sensor) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("---Сенсорный монитор---\n{0}", b);//Вывод Сенсоров
            }
            m:
            string Type;
            while (true)//Цикл для правильного ввода названия мониторов
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Какой тип монитора Вы хотите купить, LCD или Sensor ");
                Type = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Type == "LCD" || Type == "Sensor") break;
                else Console.WriteLine("Пожалуйста, введите правильный тип");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Теперь модель монитора");
            string Model = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Type == "LCD")
                {
                    var test = from i in Katalog_LCD
                               where i.Model == Model
                               select i;
                    foreach (LCD i in test)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nВы выбрали этот монитор: \n{0}", i);

                        Console.WriteLine("При покупке LCD монитора с tv-тюнером, стоимостью более 5000 гривен, предоставляется скидка 5%\nСтоимость tv-тюнерa {0} гривен\nЖелатете купить tv-тюнер?", i.Tv_tuner);
                        string tv_tuner = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (tv_tuner == "+")
                        {
                            if (i.value > 5000)
                            {
                                i.Price();
                                Console.WriteLine("Вы купили LCD монитор и ТВ-тюнер.\nСумма к оплате сo скидкой {0} гривен.", i.value);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Сумма Вашей покупки не достаточна для данyой акции.");
                            }

                        }
                        else if (tv_tuner == "-" && tv_tuner == "+")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Вы купили LCD монитор.\nСумма к оплате {0} гривен.", i.value);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else if (Type == "Sensor")
                {
                    var test = from i in Katalog_Sensor
                               where i.Model == Model
                               select i;
                    foreach (Sensor i in test)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали этот монитор: \n{0}", i);
                        Console.WriteLine("Желаете взять кредит на 12 месяцев?");
                        string kredit = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (kredit == "+")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Вы взяли кредит, суммой {0} гривен, на 12 месяцев, под 3%.", i.value);
                            i.Price();
                            Console.WriteLine("Ежемесячная сумма погашения кредита, составляет {0} гривен.", i.value);
                        }
                        else if (kredit == "-")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Вы купили сенсорный монитор. Сумма к оплате {0} гривен.", i.value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            Console.WriteLine("Приходите к нам ещё.");
            string start = Console.ReadLine();
            if (start != null)
            goto m;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```